# Breaking out of a jquery function

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I have a page with 22 different forms that use ajax to send json to my server-side code. I have one form that needs to be submitted via a normal post, i'm attempting to break out of the function and let it process normally. It appears to work fine, the form is submitted it behaves as normal, afterwords if you submit another form the page refreshes, this can be duplicated every time.

```
$("form").submit(function(e) {
 if( $('input[name="ticketpost"]').val() === "true" ) {
    return;
 }
e.preventDefault();
... 
ajax/json stuff
```

My other function to trigger the submit of the special form is as follows:

```
$(".TicketPost").click(function() {
 $("#ticketpost").submit();
});
```

I thank you ahead of time for your help.

Comment: Have you tried returning false? Maybe if you use `return false;`, instead of `return;`, that will prevent form submission. You can also just `e.preventDefault();` before `return;`

Comment: returning false will make it behave like preventDefault() and the submit will cease in all forms. I want it to just break out of the function, not stop the submit.

Comment: What does the submit function for the special form look like?

Comment: It uses the html markup to declare the target, action and method of the form submit, which on every other form is not used, nor declared.

Comment: Why not just exclude the special form from your selector? Like `$("form").not("#ticketpost").submit(function(e) {`... or `$("form:not(#ticketpost)").submit(function(e) {`...

Answer (score 0):

Try adding e.preventDefault also in TicketPost click function

```
$(".TicketPost").click(function(e) {
e.preventDefault(); 
$("#ticketpost").submit();
});
```